What property a ring extension of UFDs $R\subseteq S$ must have, such that for $a,b\in R$, $a | b$ in $S \implies a | b$ in $R$?
Let $R,S$ be two UFDs, and $R \subseteq S$, a ring extension with the following property (P) $$(\forall a,b\in R) (\ a|b \ in \ S \longrightarrow a|b  \ in  \ R).$$
Question: What are some conditions that can be put on the ring extension of UFDs such that it satisfies (P).
For example for field extension $k\subseteq K$ then $k[x_1 \dots x_n] \subseteq K[x_1 \dots x_n]$ satisfies $(P)$. I know of an inductive proof, but maybe there is a more fundamental reason based on the extension why this happens?
I've been told using notion of 'flatness' one could formulate such a condition, but I would like to know if a more elementary condition exists for UFDs.

For nonzero $a$, we have that $a|b$ in $R$ (resp. $S$) iff $b/a \in R$ (resp. $S$), where $b/a$ is considered an element of $Frac(R)$, and the case $a=0$ doesn't affect the answer. In light of this, your property (P) is equivalent to $S \cap Frac(R) = R$. Is this the sort of condition you're looking for? You might consider it simply a rephrasing of the question and you're asking for some sufficient conditions that are practically easier to check?
By the way, I haven't said anything about UFDs specifically. What I've said should work for arbitrary domains.

Thanks for answer, but I am looking for something more, a more non-trivial condition. For example, that would work on the example that I have given.

I think this is a good answer - it tells you that $S$ has to be $R$ with some subset of $R$ inverted, $S = D^{-1}R$ for some $D\subset S$. This you can formulate in commutative algebra as well.

@SomeCallMeTim Yes, it definitely is a good answer, but I am looking more for a condition for UFD. I strongly believe(a bit naively) that there must be one, which would also help for my example with the polynomial fields.
